General approach to comparing consonant and consonant cluster similarity from first principles?
I have asked several questions on StackOverflow recently, the last one being What's going wrong in these weighted jaccard sum calculations for comparing the pronunciation of consonant clusters?
Where I'm completely lost is the basics of what tools and algorithms and approaches I should be taking advantage of exactly.
Assume I don't know much:

I don't know how I should group and categorize my features / feature vectors.
I don't know which numerical values to assign to the different feature vectors.
I don't know which algorithms I should use to calculate similarity given I have numerical feature vector embeddings (from the last step).

I have spent at least 24 hours over the past week trying to understand these basics as it applies to my problem, but so far I haven't written working code, so my first principles of NLP strategies and approaches is off somehow. I need to clarify the basics.
Can you outline roughly how I would do this from scratch? What do I need to define? I know I need to define the meaning of "closeness" clearly, but how can I go about doing that?! How do I assign numerical values to each consonant so they are nicely grouped according to my subjective feelings/intuition? Then how do I properly calculate similarity between consonants and consonant clusters after figuring out the proper numerical / vector values?
This question shouldn't require any knowledge of phonetics or linguistics, a great answer would simply outline how I would go about solving this problem, not the actual solution to the problem. Once I know where I need to go, I can start going there, and solve the problem instance. But first I need to know what I need to do, and ChatGPT/AI/StackOverflow hasn't been much help yet, so asking here on the DataScience SE :)
